# Click a button with <span> value

Tags: html, vba, button

I have been working on this for a couple of days now. I am trying to navigate a website. My next step is to click a button. Unfortunately, the URL is dependent on a previous choice so I can't just follow the link.

Here is the HTML for the button I am trying to click:

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="greybutton" href="/pro/workouts/wizard?clientId=58806">
    <span>Create a New Workout</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently, I login to a website, enter a value into a search box, the new info pops up, I tab over to click a button. Now, on a new page, I want to click another button but can't figure it out.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub TestWebsite()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://functionalmovement.com/login?return=%2F" & ActiveCell)
Do
    If ie.readyState = 4 Then
        ie.Visible = True
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("Username").Value = Range("B3")
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("Password").Value = Range("B4")
Do While ie.Busy
Loop
    ie.Document.forms(0).submit
Do While ie.Busy
Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ie.Navigate ("http://functionalmovement.com/pro/clients" & ActiveCell)
Do
    If ie.readyState = 4 Then
        ie.Visible = True
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop
ie.Document.forms(1).all("gvClients$DXFREditorcol1").Value = Range("B6")
ie.Document.forms(1).all("gvClients$DXFREditorcol1").Select

SendKeys String:="{enter}", Wait:=True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

SendKeys String:="{tab}"
SendKeys String:="{tab}"
SendKeys String:="{tab}"
SendKeys String:="{tab}"
SendKeys String:="{tab}"
SendKeys String:="{enter}"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

Here is where I want the code to click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link you're trying to click doesn't have an `id`, you'll need to find it by tag name or class name.

If the `<span>` element always has that text, you can use `GetElementsByTagName()` to return all `<span>` elements, and then find the one matching the text shown (`"Create a New Workout"`).

Once you've found the `<span>`, you can access its parent using the `ParentElement` property and then call the `Click()` function.

This should do the trick:

```
Dim e
For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.InnerText = "Create a New Workout" Then

        ' Found the <span>. Now click its parent (<a>)...           
        e.ParentElement.Click
        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! This worked perfectly and helped me with some other issues.